# Scrapy, problems to have all informations

Tags: python, scrapy

I would like to use scrapy to have a database with the name of the dishes, the ingredients and the preparation time. So, I can have the name of the dishes of the 7 pages but I don't know how to proceed to tell the script to enter a dish and to take the ingredients and preparation time for each dish.

```
import os
import logging

import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class RecipesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'recipes'
    
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.cuisineaz.com/categories/plats/fast-food-cat48849",
    ]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        recipes = response.css('div.tile_content')
        for recipe in recipes:
            yield {
                'name': recipe.css('a.tile_title::text').get(),
            }
            
        try:
            next_page = response.css('li.pagination-next a').attrib["href"]
        except KeyError:
            logging.info("No next page. Terminating crawling process.")
        else:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)


# Name of the file where the results will be saved
filename = "2_cuisineaz.json"

# If file already exists, delete it before crawling (because Scrapy will concatenate the last and new results otherwise)
if filename in os.listdir('/Users/pierreduval/Desktop/Test'):
        os.remove('/Users/pierreduval/Desktop/Test + filename')

# Declare a new CrawlerProcess with some settings
process = CrawlerProcess(settings = {
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'LOG_LEVEL': logging.INFO,
    "FEEDS": {
        'results/' + filename : {"format": "json"},
    }
})

# Start the crawling using the spider you defined above
process.crawl(RecipesSpider)
process.start()
```

Thank you very much !
Have a good day

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Nnl.png)[image: 1]

[The page that I have scraped (name of dishes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbWJm.jpg)[image: 2]

[The informations that I want when you click on dishes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XUQu.png)[image: 3]

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. Avoid images and provide code as text --> How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: @Pierreduval please add your code as text

Comment: @SuperUser, Ok I have edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added comments, read them, search the doc, and if you still don't understand something then ask me.

```py
import logging
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class RecipesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'recipes'

    start_urls = ["https://www.cuisineaz.com/categories/plats/fast-food-cat48849"]

    def parse(self, response):
        # list of all the recipes urls on the page
        all_links = response.xpath('//section[@id="listRecettes"]//article/div/a/@href').getall()
        for link in all_links:
            # request recipe page
            yield scrapy.Request(url=f'https://www.cuisineaz.com{link}', callback=self.parse_recipe)

        # get the url of the next page
        next_page = response.xpath('//li[@class="pagination-next"]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            # the default callback is 'parse'
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0]+next_page)

    # parse the recipe page
    def parse_recipe(self, response):
        ingredients = response.xpath('//section[contains(@class, "ingredients")]/ul/li/span/text()').getall()
        preparation_time = response.xpath('//section[contains(@class, "instructions")]//li/span/text()').get()

        yield {
            'ingredients': ingredients,
            'preparation_time': preparation_time,
        }

# Name of the file where the results will be saved
filename = "2_cuisineaz.json"

# Declare a new CrawlerProcess with some settings
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'LOG_LEVEL': logging.INFO,
    "FEEDS": {
        f'results/{filename}': {"format": "json",
                                'overwrite': True,  # instead of checking if the file exists just overwrite it
                                'encoding': 'utf8'
                                },
    }
})

# Start the crawling using the spider you defined above
process.crawl(RecipesSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The code works perfectly.
Now I'll try to scrape the elements before (here it's on the "street food" recipes and I'll try on the other categories). However, it is necessary to put a Timestamp to not be banned?

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if the solution works for your case. That’s how you say thanks on stackoverflow

Comment: I can't upvoting I think, I need 15 reputation to cast a vote. But I think I have accepted answer. Think's for the tip :)